# Reduce all child elements inside an element by a certain %?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say I have a `.parent` element. I want every child element in `.parent` to decrease in size (width, font-size) by 20% if my media query goes under 600px `@media (max-width: 600px) {}`.

Any easy way I could do this?

Edit:  `.post` is the parent element

```
<div class="post">              

        <img src="/media/wallpaper.jpg" class="thumbnail">

        <div class="post_text_div">
                <h1>test</h1>
        </div>
            <h5 class="username">username</h5>
            <span class="timesince">
                2 days
            </span>
            <span class="number_of_comments">
                <p>0</p>
            <img src="/static/images/commentIcon.png">
            </span>

    </div>
```

Comment: This may be possible, but in most cases it would just be a case of writing between 5 and 10 nice and simple media queries. So I'd just recommend doing that. Unless you have a strong argument not to

Comment: Added code in edit

Comment: You'll find that a blanket 20% size change won't scale properly since 20% of 500px is going to be proportionally greater than 20% of 10px. Instead, you'll come to realize that creating a media query and setting the width/font-size of the individual items that need changing will be the best approach.

Comment: @Zorgan Do you want to target only the child elements of .post class or you also want to target the children of the child elements
like do you also want to target the  h1 of the  .post_text_div ?

Comment: You can check the example [ https://jsfiddle.net/LghgLu7j/38/ ] I'm not sure about CSS you already have. So I assumed width and font-size. Maybe this will help you.

Comment: @MostafaBaezid thanks that's very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I' using this code to achieve a resizing:

```
$('.parent').resizable({
    resize: function (e, ui) {
        var resizedWidth = $(this).outerWidth()/$(this).data("width");
        var resizedHeight = $(this).outerHeight()/$(this).data("height");

        $(this).find("*").each(function (i, element) {
            var width = $(element).data("width") * resizedWidth;
            var height = $(element).data("height") * resizedHeight;
            var fontsize = $(element).data("fontSize") * ((resizedHeight > resizedWidth) ? resizedWidth : resizedHeight);
            $(element).css({
                "width": width,
                "height": height,
                "font-size": fontsize
            });
        });
    },
});
```

---

This code will kind of **initialize your element**:

```
$('.parent').each(function(){
    $(this).data("height", $(this).outerHeight());
    $(this).data("width", $(this).outerWidth());
});
```

This code will adjust your properties (Height, Width, fontSize)

```
$('.parent *').each(function(){
    $(this).data("height", $(this).outerHeight());
    $(this).data("width", $(this).outerWidth());
    $(this).data("fontSize", parseInt($(this).css("font-size")));
});
```

Just add `.parent` class to your parent-container.

---

**But I really recommend you to use media queries. 100% safer & easier solution :)**

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yeah definitely but is there a better way than to manually do every media query for every width?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no easier solution then media query. I can recommend you using **percentage values** instead of **pixel values**. For adjusting font size have a look at https://plugins.jquery.com/textfill/! @Zorgan